# openshift imagestream doesn't track private docker repo

Tags: image, docker, openshift, openshift-origin

I have an image stream defined as below with openshift origin.  It will automatically pick up any tags defined in the docker repo when i create, import, or update the image stream object in openshift.  When i push images via docker (i.e. `docker push <private-repo-host-and-port>/myimage`) the image stream doesn't update with the new image in docker.  I have to manually update the image stream or re-import it or create it afresh.  Furthermore, I also have an openshift build set up which outputs to the image stream, and when the build completes successfully it pushes the build's output image to the private docker repo, but the image stream doesn't pick up on this unless i re-import or update or recreate the image stream - it doesn't do it automatically.  I have deployment configs set up to pick up on the updates to the image stream, and it does trigger new deployments when the image stream updates, but i have to update the image stream manually.

How can i get the imagestream to update automatically when the backing private docker repo that it's based up updates?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ImageStream
metadata:
  name: isname
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    deployment-id: master
    name: isname
    namespace: mynamespace
spec:  
  dockerImageRepository: '<private-repo-host-and-port>/myimage'
  tags:
    - name: latest
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: '<private-repo-host-and-port>/myimage:latest'
      importPolicy:
        scheduled: true
```

let me konw if there are other configs needed

Comment: That is expected default behaviour for the case where an image is in an external image registry. Immediate triggering of image triggers when an image is updated only applies to images in the internal image registry. That is what you are triggering when you use ``oc import-image`` as it pulls the image into the internal registry. From memory there is a setting for having external image registry polled at some interval to check for updates, but can't quickly find it right now.

Answer (score 3):

Read:

- https://blog.openshift.com/image-streams-faq/

> 6: How can I tell the system to periodically import my tag? When we
>   are working with an external registry, we would like to be able to
>   periodically re-import the image to get latest security updates, etc.
>   To do so we will use a --scheduled flag for the oc tag command like
>   so:
>
> oc tag docker.io/python:3.6.0 python:3.6 --scheduled
>
> This will inform the system that this particular Image Stream Tag
>   should be periodically checked for updates. Currently, this period is
>   a cluster-wide setting, and by default, it is set to 15 minutes.
>
> Only an Image Stream Tag pointing to an external docker registry can
>   be periodically checked for updates.
>
> To remove the periodical check, re-run above command but omit the
>   --scheduled flag. This will reset its behavior to default

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What i noticed is that if i have an internal integrated registry it does eventually pick up on new images, but it polls like every 15 minutes.  Without the internal registry it does not poll (or maybe it did but i didn't wait 15 min).  For simplicity, i'd like to avoid the internal integrated registry since i already have access to a private repo thats managed by not me :-).  It'd be nice to know how to increase that polling interval

Comment: i think i found it - in master-config.yml - scheduledImageImportMinimumIntervalSeconds defaults to 900.  I'll try like 30 seconds

Comment: as an update, decreasing scheduledImageImportMinimumIntervalSeconds didn't seem to do anything.  I got it working howerever when i added the itegrated registry.  I cannot push, pull or use the registry, but at least the image stream tags update when the backing docker image:tag is updated.

Comment: If you have an integrated registry, if it is set up correctly you should be able to log into it using ``docker`` and push/pull to it.

Comment: I got the internal registry working - it was a little bit of a hassle because I'm behind a proxy and openshift loves to use ips and not fdqns.  The image streams work now and auto-update/track docker repos.  Without the integrated registry, image streams don't seem to update an track arbitrary docker repos.  Image streams only update in the presence of the integrated registry even if im not pushing/pulling to it.